# PHP $_POST variable not set when going back to the form when user input is not correct

Tags: php

I have a form on one php page. Input values are submitted to another php page where they are processed. When values are incorrect or missing I go back to the form using:

```
header('Refresh: 3; url=biertjetoevoegen.php;')
```

The problem is that at this time the $_POST variables are not SET anymore, so the user has to re-enter all the data....

How can I go back to the form without losing the `$_POST` variables, not using `$_SESSION` variables?

Comment: *"possibly without using $_Session variables."* - Yepper! `$_SESSION` actually ;-) `$_Session` and `$_SESSION` are two different animals.

Comment: Might I ask why without `$_SESSION` variables ?

Comment: Why use them if you already have $_POST variables...

Comment: $_COOKIE ? Can't you use it too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to redirect user to another page that has posted data to, you have to send data yourself to that page (by $_SESSION or $_GET or any other ways), but you should not do it yourself.

The best way is to set your action property of your form to be the same as your html form page and the page that you validate data (page that contains your php code).

- Note that all PHP frameworks do this.

Comment: You mean I have to do it all, that is: the form the validation and the messages about incorrect user entry or missing data, in one page?

Comment: Not exactly in one page. To be exact "**in one url**". And how to handle this depends on your implementation. It will be hard if you are not using any framework and no structure (like mvc).